# How to describe keyboard shorcuts?

Tags: discussion

What's the best way to describe a keyboard shortcut in a question? For instance, if I'm talking about a shorcut that consists of the Ctrl and the + keys pressed together.
Should I describe it as Ctrl++ (style used in ubuntu's "keyboard shortcuts" window), C^+ (emacs style), or something else?

I tried using angled brackets (< and >) around each key, but I think the editor treated them as html formatting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> is probably the most understandable. To make it:

```
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>
```

I think Emacs formatting would confuse a lot of Ubuntu desktop users.

Also, unless you're specifically referring to the <kbd>+</kbd>-only key on the number pad, it's probably a good idea to write <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>. (Edit: See Marcel's point below.)

For keyboard shortcuts in a question title, it [looks like](https://superuser.com/search?q=ctrl) the Ctrl++ form is most commonly used. While this form has more potential for ambiguity, it's probably best to clutter titles as little as possible and let your question clarify the meaning.

---

On a side note, if you ever need to type inequality signs you can use the [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) `&lt;` and `&gt;` to type < and >, respectively.

And one more thought: It should go without saying, but, for everyone reading this, [please don't abuse the <kbd> tag.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/23571#23571)

Comment: Ok thanks. Any suggestion for the question title?

Comment: Updated with my recommendation for question titles.

Comment: Regarding writing Ctrl+Shift++ for the Ctrl++ shortcut: Please do *not* do this! You may need the shift key to get a + on an US keyboard layout but this is not true for many other layouts (e.g. German). Ctrl++ should be clear for everyone.